# Improving a try/catch

Tags: java, programming-practices, patterns-and-practices

I'm a python programmer trying to get to grips with Java's inflexibility; I'm trying to parse a date from a string into a `Calendar` object

```
private Calendar parsedDate ( String dateString ) throws Exception {
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  DateFormat format;
  Date date;
  try {
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    date = format.parse(dateString);
    calendar.setTime(date);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.print("wrong date format");
        calendar = null;
  }
  return calendar;
}

----
Main method
----

Calendar pd;
try {
  pd = parsedDate("01/01/2016");
  if(pd != null) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    System.out.println("A problem");
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I was hoping I could make the main method code snippet more succinct by taking out the try/catch - since I'm already testing if it's null, but if I do that then Java (well, eclipse) complains about `Unhandled exception type Exception` - do I really need both sets of try/catch, or is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Your try/catch there at the bottom has a different purpose, doesn't it?  The `ParseException` try/catch is all that's needed in that `parsedDate` function.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hmm, what will `exception` catch additionally?

Comment: The method's name should be a verb like `parseDate(String dateString)` or `parseCalendar(String dateString);` .

Comment: `main` can be declared to throw exceptions.  They'll be caught by the VM's uncaught exception handler and their stack traces will be printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `parsedDate` method doesn't need the `throws Exception` clause because the exception is already being caught.

The compiler looks at the method signature when a method is called and sees `throws Exception`, so it expects you to handle it.

Comment: Ah, right. One more reason to not bother with checked exceptions.

Comment: The simple solution is not to declare that your code may throw exceptions, when it won't.  In general "throws Exception" is a bad code smell in anything but throwaway code you don't intend to maintain.  If you're using a good IDE, such as Eclipse, then make use of its ability to warn you of un-caught exceptions.  If it doesn't flag any, there's no need to add any new "throws" or "catch" clauses.

Comment: Anyways. If *null* is not a processable result, don't return null. Let ParseException be thrown. In this example looks like null Calendar means the end of the process. Just keep the catch and remove the *if*